# Double populate on Model.find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an Order model:

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 order_items: [{
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'OrderItem',
  required: true
 }],
 user: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User',
  required: true
 },
 shipping_address: {
  type: String,
  required: true
 },
 total_price: {
  type: Number
 }
});
```

And OrderItem model:

```
const orderItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 product_id: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Product',
  required: true
 },
 quantity: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
 },
 unit_price: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
 }
});
```

And Product model:

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: {
  type: Map,
  of: String,
  required: true
 },
 unit_price: {
  type: Number,
  required: true
 }
});
```

I tried to do double populate on find Order in the request like this:

```
const findOrder = await Order.find({ user: user_id }).populate('order_items').populate({ path: 'order_items.product_id', select: 'name' });
```

But I get only the first populate. When I tried the following:

```
const findOrder = await Order.find({ user: user_id }).populate('order_items').populate({ path: 'product_id', select: 'name' });
```

I got this error:

> Cannot populate path `product_id` because it is not in your schema.
> Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.

How can I get the product's name in a nested populate request?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
const findOrder = await Order.find({ user: user_id })
  .populate({
    path: 'order_items',
    populate: {
        path: 'product_id',
        select: 'name'
    } 
  }).exec();
```

For more information about the population across multiple levels read [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate).